# loading image from supabase storage return 403

Tags: next.js13, supabase

I'm using Supabase with Nextjs, I have setup a custom loader for Supabase:

```
export default function supabaseLoader({
    src,
    width,
    quality,
}: SupabaseLoaderProps) {
    const url = new URL(
        `${process.env
            .NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!}/storage/v1/render/image/public/${src}`
    );
    url.searchParams.set('width', width.toString());
    url.searchParams.set('quality', (quality || 75).toString());
    return url.href;
}
```

on Supabase storage, I have a bucket named "static-assets" marked as public with the following policy:

```sql
((bucket_id = 'static-assets'::text) AND ((storage.extension(name) = 'jpg'::text) OR (storage.extension(name) = 'png'::text)) AND (lower((storage.foldername(name))[1]) = 'public'::text) AND (auth.role() = 'anon'::text))
```

target roles: "Defaults to all (public) roles if none selected"

The preferred behavior is to load some images as public assets regardless of user auth state, but still benefit from image transformation features.

Comment: Could you share some sample values of what could come into `src` variable? Also some sample of what you get for console logging `url` variable might help us assist you.